# Equal strings auto updating (List object reference)

Tags: python, list, object-reference

I recently did an exam for university and I got asked what would be the output of this program:

```
def fun(x):
    y=x
    x.append(4)
    print(str(x)+" "+str(y))

fun(["one","two",3,5.0])
```

I answered that the y list would be `["one","two", 3,5.0]` and after appending 4 to it, the x list would be equal to the same but with a 4 at the end of it. To my surprise, when I printed both lists, they were equal even though the x list update was performed after establishing an equality between both lists. Why did this happen?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clone or copy a list in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have given reference if list x to y. So any change in list x would also affect list y.

```
y=x
```

For example:

```
>>> x = ["one","two",3,5.0]
>>> y = x
>>> x[3] = 4
>>> x
['one', 'two', 3, 4]
>>> y
['one', 'two', 3, 4]
```

Here both x and y have same identity.

```
>>> x is y
True
>>> id(x)
3073118540L
>>> id(y)
3073118540L
```

You can better understand this using [***swampy***](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/swampy/) module:

```
>>> from swampy.Lumpy import Lumpy
>>> lump = Lumpy()
>>> x = ["one","two",3,5.0]
>>> y = x
>>> x[3] = 4
>>> lump.object_diagram()
```

[image]

---

What you were expecting can be achieved by copying the list x to list y like this:

```
>>> x = ["one","two",3,5.0]
>>> y = x[:]
>>> x.pop()
5.0
>>> x
['one', 'two', 3]
>>> y
['one', 'two', 3, 5.0]
```

So by copying the content from x to y, they don't hold the same identity:

```
>>> id(x)
3073240428L
>>> id(y)
3073240588L
>>> x is y
False
```

Using swampy:

```
>>> from swampy.Lumpy import Lumpy
>>> lump = Lumpy()
>>> x = ["one","two",3,5.0]
>>> y = x[:]
>>> lump.draw_object()
>>> lump.object_diagram()
```

[image]

For better explanation visit here [***How do I copy an object in Python?***](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-copy-an-object-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Actually `x` and `y` are labels that reference to object so when you assign `y=x` you crate 2 reference to one object , so when you change one of them you change the main object .

Also you may note that `x` , `y` are local variables when you made inplace changes like `append` you changed the main object , but if you use assignment python create a new object :

```
>>> def fun(x):
...     y=x
...     x=x+[3]
...     print(str(x)+" "+str(y))
... 
>>> fun(["one","two",3,5.0])
['one', 'two', 3, 5.0, 3] ['one', 'two', 3, 5.0]
```

in-place changes to objects do not classify names as locals; only actual name
assignments do. For instance, if the name L is assigned to a list at the top level of a
module, a statement `L = X` within a function will classify L as a local, but `L.append(X)`
will not. In the latter case, we are changing the list object that L references, not L itself—
L is found in the global scope as usual, and Python happily modifies it without requiring
a global (or `nonlocal` ) declaration. As usual, it helps to keep the distinction between
names and objects clear: changing an object is not an assignment to a name.(*from learning python by mark lutz*)

```
class A:
  global L
  L=[1,2]
  def b(self):
     L=[0,0]
     return L
  def c(self):
     L.append(5)
     return L

a=A()
print a.b()

print a.c()
```

result :

```
[0, 0]
[1, 2, 5]
```

Comment: could you provide an example how this looks if a name L is assigned to a list at the top of the module ?

Answer (score 0):

Because list are `mutable` objects. see [Python Data Model](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/datamodel.html#objects-values-and-types)

```
In [1]: a = [1]

In [3]: b = a

In [4]: b
Out[4]: [1]

In [5]: b.append(2)

In [6]: a
Out[6]: [1, 2]

In [7]: b
Out[7]: [1, 2]

In [8]: id(a), id(b)
Out[8]: (140260765233376, 140260765233376)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the name `y` is bound to the same list as `x`

```
y = x
```

This is a great drawing of how that looks:

```
 x   y
 |  /
 | /
["one", "two", 3, 5.0]
```

---

```
x.append(4)
```

---

```
 x   y
 |  /
 | /
["one", "two", 3, 5.0, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following example. It will help you to get differences between assignment operator and method like copy(shallow), deepcopy.

```
>>> import copy
>>> l1 = [1,2, [1,2]]
>>> l1
[1, 2, [1, 2]]
#Create l2, l3, l4 by copy, deepcopy method and normal assignment.
>>> l2 = copy.copy(l1)
>>> l3 = copy.deepcopy(l1)
>>> l4 = l1
>>> l2
[1, 2, [1, 2]]
>>> l3
[1, 2, [1, 2]]
>>> l4
>>> [1, 2, [1, 2]]
#-----------------------Now Append value to l1
>>> l1.append(9)
>>> l1
[1, 2, [1, 2], 9]
>>> l2
[1, 2, [1, 2]]
>>> l3
[1, 2, [1, 2]]
>>> l4
>>> [1, 2, [1, 2], 9]
#-----------------------Now Append value to l1[2]
>>> l1[2].append(5)
>>> l1
[1, 2, [1, 2, 5], 9]
>>> l2
[1, 2, [1, 2, 5]]
>>> l3
[1, 2, [1, 2]]
>>> l4
>>> [1, 2, [1, 2, 5], 9]
#------------------------
```